Morse function on a surface and a homotopy of a circle embedding
Let $M$ be a closed oriented surface, $f : M \to \mathbb{R}$ a Morse function, and $\varphi : S^1 \to M$ an embedding of the circle in the surface $M$. I am asked, on a practice qualifying exam, to show that $\varphi$ can be homotoped to an embedding $\psi : S^1 \to M$ for which $f \circ \psi$ is Morse.
I only have vague ideas. Maybe consider how $\varphi(S^1)$ moves under the gradient flow of $f$ and hope that at some point the restriction of $f$ to this new curve is Morse. Or, somehow use the fact that the Morse functions are dense in the space of smooth functions $M \to \mathbb{R}$. Any help would be appreciated.
